# Is there a VBScript implementation of Markdown?

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic, markdown, markup

Does anybody know a VBScript implementation of [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)?

I want to use it in my webpages written in Classic ASP to convert Markdown markup to HTML.

UPDATE Jan 26: Nobody?

Comment: yikes. there's still people doing classic ASP??!! That's been obsolete for... what, 10?, 12? years.

Comment: Why be so contemptuous? SO is meant for helping each other with programming issues, not for criticizing choices of other people. Yes, I sometimes use Classic ASP, it works fine for me!

Comment: In a way he’s right though. ASP’s obsolescence pretty much ensures that not a lot of new libraries are developed for it so finding a Markdown library for it will probably be pretty hard. And switching to ASP.NET is kind of obvious …

Comment: Though brought in a less clear manner, Spudley does raise a point regarding your search for an answer. Lack of users/development -> lack of new ideas being implemented. It might be very likely that nobody has done such a thing and that nobody ever will.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Maybe you're right, but Markdown itself is also already 6 years old, so I was hoping for a VB dialect implementation.

Comment: question is quite old, but I have to ask. why just don't you use a javascript implementation on server-side with classic asp? it would be ironic to use, stackexchange's [pagedown](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) :)

Answer (score 4):

Just posting an answer to this since I was just looking and this is what comes up at the top of the search.

There is a jScript implementation (e.g. server side js) wrapped in a classic asp/vbScript class for converting markdown into HTML:

https://github.com/nagaozen/asp-xtreme-evolution/blob/master/lib/axe/classes/Parsers/markdown.asp